# Erro 403.14 Forbidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Quando vou abrir a página em asp.net, este erro é apresentado:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Estava funcionando normalmente. Alterei uns arquivos e parou de funcionar, voltei os arquivos e mesmo assim não funciona.

Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Comment: O que exatamente você está tentando acessar? Qual o *Application Pool* deste site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser:

1. Problemas de permissões na pasta do projeto
2. Problemas de permissões na configuração do projeto no IIS.
3. Arquivo padrão para listagem do projeto.

Se nada disso resolver, dê mais detalhes do problema para que possamos ajudar.